# How to write A :: B :: C => D given A :: B :: C and (A, B, C) => D?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose I have an `HList` of type `A :: B :: C` and a function `(A, B, C) => D`. How to write a function `A :: B :: C => D` in the simplest and most idiomatic way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is method `toProduct` in `syntax.std.function`:

```
import shapeless._
import syntax.std.function._
def testf(d: Double, l: Long, i: Int): String = s"$d, $l, $i"

(testf _).toProduct
// Double :: Long :: Int :: HNil => String = <function1>
```

See [Feature overview: shapeless 2.0.0/Facilities for abstracting over arity](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3A-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity).